# Suppress a specific type of exceptions in nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, gitlab-ci

I set up a CI pipeline (Gitlab CI if that matters) for my latest Python project and added several test cases for things I still want to implement. In each test case I raise a `NotImplementedError` since, well, it has not been implemented yet.

```
import unittest

class GenericTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_stuff(self):
        """I'll fill this in when I come around to it."""
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Generally, I want these tests to fail, since do not yet work properly. However, when I push to my repository and the tests are run on the CI system, I would like to skip these tests. I already know they will 'fail' and they mask actual failing tests.

Is there a way to suppress these exceptions, or a specific type of exception (like `IKnowThisWillFailError`), so that the affected tests are not counted as 'failed'?

Comment: Are you really raising the error in the test?
What about creating the method in the application and raise the error there, then you can except the error in the test until you implemented the feature.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I do, since it tests functionality that needs to be added to an already existing function and it (should) test complicated edge cases. So in order to raise the error in the application, I would need to implement the edge case detection and handling first. I realize that this is not proper TDD procedure though, as it makes the "test case" more of a ToDo and a reminder that this test is still missing than an actual test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
import unittest

class GenercTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_stuff(self):
        """I'll fill this in when I come around to it."""
        raise unittest.SkipTest("IKnowThisWillFail")
```

your CI system probably can differentiate between skipped and failed tests

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    # code
except IKnowThisWillFailError:
    pass
except:
    # catch
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this does not help with my problem :( But as a general hint for answering question on this site: code-only answer without explanation are consider bad answers on SO (see [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality?lq=1) for reference). By adding explanations to your answers they become more readable and accessible which increases your chance of getting upvotes.